# Python Type Hint for parent class function that returns same type as calling class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-typing

Is there a way to type hint a parent class function to show that it returns the same type as the actual calling class?

Consider this:

- class B inherits from class A  and implements a function func_b
- class A has a function func_a that returns whatever type is passed in
- An instance of class B, “b”, calls func_a as follows: b2 = b.func_a()
- Is there a way to typehint func_a (or something else) so that the IDE sees b2.func_b() as a valid call?

'''

```
import __future__

class A:
    def func_a(self) -> "A":
        return self
class B(A):
    def func_b(self) -> None:
        print("func_b was called")
a = A()
a.func_a()
b = B()
b2 = b.func_a()
b2.func_a()
# IDE doesn't recognize that b2 is of class B and so b2.func_b() is white not yellow
# but still works
b2.func_b()
```

'''

**func_b() is white rather than yellow:**
[image: func_b() is white rather than yellow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Self` from `typing`:

```
from typing import Self

class A:
    def func_a(self) -> Self:
        return self
```

You can find more details here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/

Comment: You can use `TypeVar` if `Self` is not available: `def func_a(self: T) -> T:`